# ScriptEvaluate against specific server in cluster

Tags: stackexchange.redis

Is it possible to execute ScriptEvaluate against an specific server in a cluster?

For example trying to find out the number of keys on each instance

`_db.ScriptEvaluate("return #redis.call('keys', 'moo.*')");`